# Website URL Forwarding

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, url-rewriting, dns

I have a WordPress website accessible from a domain such as abc.com which contains a part of it dedicated on cars (a page with some links on it).  I would like to create a URL so that this cars page can be accessed directly from www.abc.com/cars

I know that I can create a folder on my hosting account called "cars" and put an index file with a META redirect to that location, however I was looking for something different as such META redirect can impact SEO.

Request 1:
Is there something that can be set from a DNS point of view to do what I am after?

Request 2 (only if possible):
If once the user hits the url www.abc.com/cars it would be great if the URL remains like that rather than showing categories and other stuff of wordpress in the URL.  Im not sure if let say the user navigated to a page with classic cars it would be possible to continue building on the url www.abc.com/cars/classic for example - I am completely unknowledgeable on this, so not sure if something like this is even possible.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this easily using htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On   
RewriteRule    ^/cars$    myPageForCarLinks.php    [NC,L]
```

As we are using the `[L]` identifier without a `301` flag, the url will remain unnchaged and simply serve the page `myPageForCarLinks.php`

*Explained*:

Within the rewrite rule we have three sections `^/cars$` and `myPageForCarLinks.php` and `[NC,L]`
The first section identifies the url that you wish to apply the rule to. In this case the url will be `/cars`. The second section is what page you want to display to the user when that url is entered. In this case when `/cars` is the url we want to serve the page `myPageForCarLinks.php` (include full directory path). We use the rul `[L]` which will enable the url to remain unchanged, as apposed to a redirect.

For a full description on what each section does and the rules that apply please visit this page https://www.addedbytes.com/articles/for-beginners/url-rewriting-for-beginners/

Comment: what does this actually do? and do i put the htaccess in the root folder where I have the wordpress installation?

Comment: Put the `.htaccess` file in the root folder, where your `index.php` folder is.

Comment: since there isn't an actual .php file for my cars page (since it's a wordpress thing), would it work if I just put the url such as http://www.example.com/cars instead of myPageForCarLinks.php?

Comment: i've set this, but for some reason getting a 404 error:

RewriteRule ^/cars$ http://www.example.com/website/categories/cars [NC,L]

Comment: If you manually put `example.com/website/categories/cars` into the web browser does it work ok? Also try using `^cars$` without the `/`

Comment: ok ive removed the "/" and ive got the redirect, however the URL in the address bar changed to the actual url of the page (didn't remain www.example.com/cars)

Comment: You could always also remove the `[NC, L]` all completely.